# Error when trying to delete data with index query in indexeddb:: index.delete is not a function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to delete data with index but I am getting error. If I delete directly with objectstore without index, there is no problem, but what I need is to delete with index.

[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Us8.png)

**Create Db Function**

```
var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
        let index = objectStore.createIndex('floorIndex', ['floorIndex']);
```

**Delete Function**

```
var floorIndexValue = "2";
    const request = window.indexedDB.open("AdminDatabase");

    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;



      const txnRoom = db.transaction('rooms', 'readwrite');
      const storeRoom = txnRoom.objectStore('rooms');

   
      const index = storeRoom.index('floorIndex');

      let query = index.delete([floorIndexValue]);

      query.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log(" Room Delete Error DB: " + event);

      };
      query.onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log(" Room Delete Succes DB: " + event);

      };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with IDBKeyRange here:

```
      const keyRangeValue = IDBKeyRange.only([getRoomButtonNumber]);

      var transaction = db.transaction("rooms", "readwrite");
      var store = transaction.objectStore("rooms");
      var index = store.index("floorIndex");
      var request = index.openCursor(keyRangeValue);

      request.onsuccess = function (event) {

        var cursor = event.target.result;
        console.log("Room Delete Succes DB: " + cursor);

        if (cursor) {
          console.log("cursor is not null");
          cursor.delete();
          cursor.continue();
        }
      };
```